# String Manipulation and rot-13

Tags: c, string, for-loop, rot13

I have to basically take the input array of characters and translate it into the result array using rot-13. So, here's what I'm thinking of doing: use a for loop and then use conditionals inside the for loop to determine whether or not to add or subtract 13 places. But what I'm having trouble with is writing the for loop.

Here's the function that I have to implement:

```
    void str_rot_13(char const input[], char result []);
```

I know that when you write a for loop, it looks something like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
```

So I have written my test cases, but the compiler won't compile.

```
#include "string.h"
#include "checkit.h"

void str_rot_13_tests(void)
{
   char input[3] = {'a', 'C', 'd'};
   char result[3] = {'n', 'P', 'q'};

   checkit_string(str_rot_13("aCd", 3), "nPq")
}

int main()
{
   str_rot_13_tests();

   return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure what I did wrong and the compiler complains about line 9. I'm thinking it has something to do with the way I wrote "checkit_string...", but I'm not too sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a nice simple example of looping over a string in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int length(char const *s)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        /* loop body is empty */
    }

    return i;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char const test[] = "hello";

    printf("String: '%s'  length: %d\n", test, length(test));
}
```

Look at just the `for` loop.  There are three parts: initialization, test, and the step.  Then there is either a single statement, or else a "block" (a set of zero or more statements enclosed in curly braces).  In my example, the block is empty (other than a human-readable comment that doesn't execute).

The initialization is executed once and should be used to set up the loop somehow; in my example, it's used to set `i` to zero.  The "test" is some expression that is evaluated before the loop body is executed; if the test evaluates false, the loop terminates, so a condition that is false before the loop even does anything will cause the loop body to never be executed.  If the test evaluates true, the loop body is executed, and after that the "step" is executed; the "step" should advance the loop somehow.  In my example, the test is checking to see whether the loop has found the terminating NUL byte yet, and the step increments the loop counter `i`.

So think about how this loop works.  We start `i` at zero, then the loop immediately checks to see if the first character in the string is a NUL byte.  If it is, the loop is already over, and our `length()` function returns 0, which is correct!  If the first byte of a string is a terminating NUL byte, then that is a "null string" and the correct length is 0.  (It's important when writing loops to think about what happens if the loop does nothing.  Loops should "do nothing" correctly; this one does.)

An interesting thing about C's `for` loop: all the parts of the loop are optional.  Here are some alternate versions of the loop; these will all work.

```
i = 0;  /* initialize i before loop */
for (; s[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    ;  /* looks weird but this is a statement that does nothing */
```

In this example, we initialize `i` outside the loop, and the initialization part is left empty.  The empty statement with a single semicolon is unusual but legal.  More often, you will see someone put something like this:  `NULL;`  The `NULL` is evaluated, but then the value isn't saved anywhere, so this is also a do-nothing statement.

```
for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0';)
{
    ++i;  /* do the step part as the loop body */
}
```

In this example, after the test, the loop body is run; this increments `i`.  Then the "step" part of the loop is omitted.

```
i = 0;  /* initialization */
for (;;)
{
    if (s[i] == '\0')  /* test */
        break;
    ++i;  /* step */
}
```

In this example, all three parts of the `for` loop are omitted, which is legal and basically means "loop forever until something stops the loop".  Then in the `if` statement, if we see the NUL byte we execute the `break` statement, which terminates the loop.  Finally we increment `i`.

Note that the initialization, test, and step are actually present; they just aren't in the `for` loop line.  For simple loops like this one, I recommend the standard form, not this weird form.

Finally, some people will write a tricky loop that increments the character pointer itself, rather than incrementing a loop variable like `i`.  Here's an example:

```
int length(char const *s)
{
    char const *start;

    for (start = s; *s != '\0'; ++s)
    {
    }

    return (s - start);
}
```

In this example, we increment the variable `s` itself.  Since it was passed as an argument, the function has its own copy and it can modify that copy without affecting anything else outside the function.  This saves a copy of the initial pointer, increments until the terminating NUL is found, then subtracts the start position from the new position to find the length.

Usually people will shorten the loop.  The test is true if the test expression is non-zero, and in a string, only the NUL byte is zero.  So the test expression can simply be `*s` and it will evaluate true if the current position is not a NUL byte:

```
int length(char const *s)
{
    char const *start;

    for (start = s; *s; ++s)
    {
    }

    return (s - start);
}
```

And finally, we could make this a bit shorter with a `while` loop:

```
int length(char const *s)
{
    char const *start = s;

    while (*s)
        ++s;

    return (s - start);
}
```

It's short and terse, but it's pretty clear once you are used to this stuff.

Comment: OMG, THANK YOU SO MUCH! You have no idea how much this helps! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! :-)  I hope you will have lots of fun learning C.

Comment: Thank you! I hope I do well! This is hard to do coming from an art background with no prior experience to programming, haha. :)

Answer (score 1):

`size = strlen(input)`, assuming `input` is a NUL terminated string, ie. simply loop until `input[i] == '\0'`. Since `input` is a `char*`, you can just increment it until `*input == '\0'`.

If it's not a NUL terminated string, then you must provide the size to `str_rot_13`, otherwise you can't tell the length of the array when it's passed to the function (as it decays to a pointer).

Comment: Thanks! This really helped! I completely forgot about the NUL.

Comment: Oh, one question. So in the for loop, would I say: for (int i = 0; input[i] != '\0'; i++)?

Comment: @KarenLee: Yeah you could do that, or `for(; *input != '\0'; input++)`, or `while (*input != '\0') { ... input++; }`. It's also best to use `size_t` as the type for an array index, even though `int` will usually suffice.

Answer (score 1):

```
char char_rot_13(char c){
   char new_c = c;

   if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
   {
      new_c = c + 13;
      if(new_c > 'z')
          new_c -= 26;
   }
   else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
   {
      new_c = c + 13;
      if(new_c > 'Z')
          new_c -= 26;
   }
   return new_c;
}
void str_rot_13(char const input[], char result []){
    while(*input){
        *result++ = char_rot_13(*input++);
    }
    *result ='\0';
}
```

TEST:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

char *str_rot_13(char const input[], char result[]){
    char *p=result;
    while(*input){
        *p++ = char_rot_13(*input++);
    }
    *p ='\0';
    return result;
}
int main (void){
    char result[128];
    assert(strcmp(str_rot_13("acd", result), "npq")==0);
    printf("%s", result);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: One question, when I'm writing the test cases and I want to use "check it_string", would I say: checkit_string(str_rot_13("acd", 3), "npq")? I'm not sure if the"3" in the parentheses is right though. :(

Comment: Don't need size string in C Because it becomes the promise at the end that there is a '\ 0'. (There is a possibility of overrun if this is the case)

Comment: @KarenLee `checkit_string(str_rot_13("acd", 3), "npq")` `char* str_rot_13(const char *, size_t )` : It ends up memory leak when returning to ensure the area a new string passed is immutable.

Comment: Is that second part of the code, the "char*...", is that something that I have to put after the checkit_string...?

Comment: @Karen That's right. I was changed to `char*` from `void` `checkit_string` from being requested it. It is customary function to the operation of the string will return a `char*` post-operation as the meaning of the other.